# How to plot all points from a file (lack of first point in plot)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have problem with plotting data from file, and more precisely from first row. The data from the firts row are always skiped in the plot and I don't know why this sytuation occurs. Do anybody know how to resolve this problem?

I enclose the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fname1 = 'data.txt'
data1 = np.genfromtxt(fname1, names=True)
cols1 = data1.dtype.names
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
ax1.grid(False)
plt.errorbar(data1[cols1[0]], data1[cols1[1]], yerr=[data1[cols1[2]],
data1[cols1[3]]], fmt='o', markersize=5, color='blue')
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)
plt.ylabel("PI")
plt.xlabel("MJD")
plt.savefig("test.png")
#plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.show()`
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first row of your `data.txt` contains column names, the solution from the question should work. Since it apparently doesn't, I assume that you don't have column names in you data file.

If you don't have column names in your data file, don't use `names=True`. Remove this argument. Then it's clear that you cannot use column names to index your array. So instead of `data1[columnname]` you need to index the array the usual way of providing row and column numbers.

```
plt.errorbar(data1[:,0], data1[:,1], yerr=[data1[:,2],data1[:,3]] )
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html):

If `names` is `True`, the field names are read from the first valid line after the first skip_header lines. If names is a sequence or a single-string of comma-separated names, the names will be used to define the field names in a structured dtype. If names is None, the names of the dtype fields will be used, if any.

I think 
`data1 = np.genfromtxt(fname1, names=False)` will solve the issue.

Comment: It doesn't work but then generates another error :/ But I checked info about this header and I filled first row with additional text. It works, but I still feel confused why this header is required (yes, I know I need to read more about it :) ). Thank you! Regards,